# C# Azure Service Bus Function gets triggered multiple times despite of the fixed delay retry

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

So I have an Azure function that will be triggered if any message lands into the queue on the Service Bus. Hence, I have the following setup:

```
[FunctionName("CallCustomerAPI")]
[FixedDelayRetry(1, "00:02:00")]
public async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("account_queue", Connection = "SBConnection")] string payload
    , int deliveryCount
    , ILogger log)
{
//Logic Here
}
```

So as we can see here, I have added a FixedDelayRetry of 2 minutes with 1 retry, which means the function will wait 2 mins for processing the message. I have configurd the following properties in my queue:

1. Max Delivery Count = 2 mins
2. Message time to live = Default (14 days)
3. Message Lock Duration = 5 mins

So here are my findings:

1. I send a message to the Service Bus queue, and the message gets picked up and inside the function, I throw an exception (in like 2 seconds)
2. The function waits for 2 minutes and after 2 minutes, the message gets picked up and runs into an exception
3. Immediately after the second run, without waiting for 2 mins, the azure function gets triggered again and like previous steps, it runs into an exception.
4. After the preceding step, the function waits for 2 mins and after 2 mins, it starts running again for the last time and then runs into an exception and then dead-lettered.

Now, that I provided the steps, I would like to know why step 3 is running abnormally without waiting for 2 mins and how to fix this issue?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages), you shouldn't be counting on this feature moving forward and instead, rely on the delivery count.

> We're removing retry policy support in the runtime for triggers other than Timer, Kafka, and Event Hubs after this feature becomes generally available (GA). Preview retry policy support for all triggers other than Timer and Event Hubs was removed in December 2022. For more information, see the Retries section.

If you wish to implement a delayed retry yourself, you can with In-Process SDK, which you seem to be using. With Isolated Worker SDK, it's impossible until the message settlement feature (the equivalent of `MessageActions`) is implemented.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. How do i implment the delayed retry with the in-process sdk?

Comment: Have the incoming message cloned and scheduled, while completing the incoming message. You'll need to coordinate `MaxDeliveryCount` for this to work properly.